# Using aux-directory when you need the output

Tags: auxiliary-files, answers, texpad

Several latex distributions have options to put aux files in a separate directory using a `-aux_directory` command-line option. I use Texpad, so I have a "hide intermediate files" option that I have on by default, but I believe the basic idea is the same.

I would like to use the [answers package](https://ctan.org/pkg/answers) to separate answers from questions. The most basic example from the documentation is below.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage{answers}
\Newassociation{sol}{Solution}{ans}
\newtheorem{ex}{Exercise}
\begin{document}
\Opensolutionfile{ans}[ans1]
\section{Problems}
\begin{ex}
  First exercise.
  \begin{sol}
    First solution.
  \end{sol}
\end{ex}
\Closesolutionfile{ans}
\section{Solutions}
\input{ans1}
\end{document}
```

Here we create a file `ans1.tex` and put the contents of the sol environments in it, and then we `\input` it at the end (the back of the book, say).

If I am using "hide intermediate files", then `ans1.tex` goes in the aux file folder and latex gets very upset about the `\input` line. I could hard-code the location of the aux file folder in the `\input` line, but then my latex would be specialized to my configuration and unable to typeset in other situations.

Of course, I could just turn off "hide intermediate files". My question, which I realize is a bit silly given the obvious fix of just turning off this setting, is: is there a way to do this sort of thing while still hiding intermediate files?

Comment: well personally I would never use such an aux-directory, but such systems typically set it up also as input directory --- after all LaTeX has to find (and seems to find) the aux-file.

Comment: redirecting the output has no advantages and means you have to configure everything, tex, bibtex, makeindex, yoru editor, .... to find the files that have been written to a non standard place.  but if you add teh output directory to your TEXINPUTS path tex will find the files.